# Looking for a word attributing the state of revealing the past

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Words like "prophetic" and "visionary" explain situations in which someone or something can predict the future. Nonetheless, I am looking for a word that embodies the ability to reveal information about the past. Here is the context:

> the development of knowledge sheds light on the [**word I am looking for**] capacities of blood. For example, a blood test could detemind who had syphilis.

Comment: Is *revelatory* a candidate?

Comment: The example seems to emphasize information about the present (who has syphilis) and not the past (e.g. whether a grandmother had a mitochondrial condition). So in its current form, I see the **diagnostic capacities of blood**, but that hardly feels like the solution for foresight : hindsight :: prophetic : ?.

Comment: sorry, I edited the example.

Comment: 'Evidentiary' (as a poorer second to 'diagnostic') with your example sentence, which still doesn't match the title question (for which you would need ' ... For example, a blood test could detemind who had had syphilis').

Answer (score 1):

According to the example you provided,

> the development of knowledge sheds light on the [word I am looking for] capacities of blood. For example, a blood test could determine who had syphilis.

I think the word you need should describe the hidden capabilities or the things that can be uncovered through blood, and not the word to convey the ability to reveal the past; but that's only my opinion. You're free to ignore this.

Maybe I can suggest a few adjective candidates for your query:

[**determining**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/determine)

[**revealing**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revealing)

[**hidden**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hidden)

[**disclosing**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disclose)

Comment: When the OP is looking for a word or a phrase, you should provide links to online dictionaries that verify the meanings you have highlighted.

Comment: @CJ DennisThanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

"Genetic" - Could work, pertains to past history.

Comment: Genetics generally relates to the characteristics passed from generation to generation, not to the medical history of an individual.